# Displaying Images using PHP/CSS

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am displaying a gallery and trying to get all images the same size.

The code below displays the image perfectly however each row is showing the same image

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result41);   
for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result41); $i++)
{
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result41);
    $upload_id = $row ['upload_id'];
    $file = $row ['FILE_NAME'];

    echo"    
    <style>
   .thumb {
    background-color: #CCC;
    background-image: url('uploads/$file');
```

HTML

```
<div id='cover' class='thumb'></div>
```

I am using `background-image: url('uploads/$file');` to display the image for each row?

Comment: so put them in `<img>`

Comment: something like this `<img src="uploads/$file" class="thumb">`

Comment: you're using the same class for each instance, that's why.

Comment: Use the `background-image` property inline with each div you are creating `<div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(...)">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if( mysql_num_rows($result41) >= 1 ) {
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result41)) {
    $upload_id = $row['upload_id'];
    $file = $row['FILE_NAME'];

    echo '<img src="uploads/'.$file.'" class="thumb">';
  }
}
```

in css:

```
.thumb {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

The html will then render each image.

If you wanted to use:

```
<div id='cover' class='thumb'></div>
```

I don't know if you have JavaScript or jQuery on `cover` but it will fail because an `id` is unique per page so you would have to do the following:

```
<div id='cover1' class='thumb'></div>
<div id='cover2' class='thumb'></div> 
<div id='cover3' class='thumb'></div>
```

Also note that `mysql_*` is depracted and will be removed. Instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 1):

Use inline css tags.

```
<div class="thumb" style="background-image: url('<?=$your_file?>')">
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using background-image in class use it in style directly.

```
<div class="thumb" style="background-image: url('uploads/$file')">
```

or if it fulfills your requirement, use img like

```
<img src="uploads/$file" class="thumb">
```